# Google Apps Script for form sets stuck at first value entered

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am writing a form to update an inventory whenever an item is ordered. In this project, there is a google sheet which is linked to a form. The form contains a script that gets the current inventory from the sheet and subtracts one from this upon order.

The form has three questions: name, size, and comment.

The issue I am getting is that the system works once, and then somehow stores the first response for each successive form submission.

For a minimal working example: I've distilled the issue to the following code, which is triggered by a form submission:

```
function updateStock() 
{
  var customer_name = "";
  const ss_id = ### I enter spreadsheet ID here ###
  const form_id = ### I enter form ID here ###

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss_id);
  var form = FormApp.openById(form_id);

  var form_resp = form.getResponses()[0];
  var customer_name = form_resp.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
  Logger.log(customer_name);
// Rest of code follows from here
}
```

Upon entry for the first form I write:

> *Name*: Peter

> *Size*: M

> *Comment:* none

Code returns:

`1:43:40 AM Info    Peter`

(If I include the rest of the code, it correctly subtracts the inventory).

Then on the next (or tenth) submission, I might submit:

> *Name*: Joe

> *Size*: L

> *Comment:* none

again, the code returns:

```
1:44:55 AM  Info    Peter
```

If I start from scratch or clear responses, I can get it to work once, but if not, the code will forever return "Peter" for the name, regardless of what I enter.

The form responses however are correct! It is just the call to

```
var form_resp = form.getResponses()[0];
var customer_name = form_resp.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
```

... that seems to have a "cached" value.

This seems like a weird bug, but am wondering if anyone has a clue as to what this might be (or, honestly, if there is a better way to achieve the same result!)

Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: That's because you're trying to access only first record of the form "getItemResponses()[0]" every time, do you want to run this function every time user submits the form?

Comment: Yes! Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. Very bad error on my part.

As vector pointed out:

The code: `form.getResponses()` returns all responses whereas I thought it was returning the *current* response (read the docs!)

Thus `form.getResponses()[0]` was naturally returning the first answer, whereas I should have written:

```
  var N = form.getResponses().length-1;
  var form_resp = form.getResponses()[N];
```

Whoops.